# getting default working directory from caller workflow to reusable workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I wanted to pass the below directory name(myfolder/python/serviceA) from the caller work flow to the reusable workflows directory. Please let me know hoe can I achieve this?

caller workflow

```
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: myfolder/python/serviceA

..

..
jobs:
  reusable-job:
    uses: <owner>/<repo>/.github/workflows/<reusable workflow>@master
    with:
      working-directory: {{ deafults.working-directory }} # something like this
```

this working directory should be available in the reusable workflow

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      working-directory:
        required: true
....
...
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: {{ inputs.working-directory }}#something like this
```

Comment: `on.workflow_call.defaults` is not available for now. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows

Comment: I guess you may intended `job.<job>.defaults` https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_iddefaultsrun

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make sure your first step in the **reusable** workflow is `- uses: actions/checkout@v3` and then the default working-directory inside a reusable workflow should work

Comment: This doesn't work for me. You can't use the `inputs` context at the `defaults` key top level, and you can't use the `defaults` key inside `workflow_call` as in the question